# Setting cookie Array of last visited products

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

How could I change my code to setting not only one product, which overwrites itself, but an array of last-visited product's id's?

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {

        $request = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route');

            if ($request === 'front_product_detail') {

                $productId = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('id');

                $cookie = new Cookie('lastVisitedProduct', $productId, time() + 3 * 31 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
                
                return $cookie;
            }
    }
```